# Post questions on GLPI to be posted in GLPI Enthusiasts

Tags: discussion

I notice that a question of mime with regards to GLPI was deemed off-topic.

So, I would like to recommend this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50300/glpi-enthusiasts) - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50300/glpi-enthusiasts for anyone who are seeking help on GLPI.

Also, I would like to ask what type of questions with regards to GLPI would be more suitable in posting in Web Applications. (Would appreciate if a question example can be list out)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that GLPI is a computer software, which is out of scope of this site since this site is for applications on websites, not locally installed applications.

Do correct me if I am wrong, but that is the first impression I get from reading the about page on the link provided in the proposal. If it is actually a web application, please do ask for the question to be reopened and explain more about the GLPI that you are talking about.

Comment: I wish you luck for the proposal on Area 51 though :D